# Why do my versions of Java differ?

Tags: java, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

If I `brew --config`, I see

```
#...
Java: 1.8.0_60
```

which is what my my OS X Java Control Panel reported until I recently updated. Now the control panel reports the new version

> Java 8 Update 65

but `brew --config` continues to report the old one.

Why do these two versions of Java differ? I haven't explicitly installed a different Java with Homebrew, and had always thought that Homebrew was reporting the version of he one Java I'm aware of: the one I installed when Java notified be of an update.

Comment: Why the close votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) and the Java Development Kit (JDK). You can have both installed and both can be at a different version. Brew will report the version of Java that is used on the command line.

- The JRE is installed in: `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/`
- The JDK is installed in: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/`

In my case the JDK was at update 20 while the JRE was at update 65. When you check for Java updates, the updater only updates the JRE. The JDK has to be manually updates apparently.

Comment: So the `Java` reported by Homebrew is the JDK, correct? That seems to work, though now I see `Java: 1.8.0_65, 1.8.0_60` (two versions). Can I just delete the old one; if so, how?

Comment: It depends. I believe that the JRE and JDK installers set the Java version used in the terminal. So the terminal will always use the latest installed version (could be JRE and JDK). As for deleting: you can delete the directory of the JRE or JDK version that you wish to remove (see my answer for paths).

Comment: `java -version` shows me the version of the JRE. Is there a way to see what version of the JDK is being used by the system. (Actually I'm no sure what the relationship is or what "could be JRE and JDK" means.)

Comment: You can use ``javac -version`` to check the JDK version.